# dropPrimaryKey in wrong order

Tags: grails, database-migration, liquibase

Using Grails database-migration I have a table in production defined like so:

```
+--------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| version      | bigint(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| basket_id    | bigint(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| gift_card_id | bigint(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

In the latest develop branch we've modified this domain to use a composite key and remove the id and version:

```
class BasketGiftCard implements Serializable {

  Basket basket
  GiftCard giftCard

  static mapping = {
    id composite: ['basket', 'giftCard']
    version false
  }
}
```

When running the dbm-gorm-diff we end up with the following:

```
changeSet(author: "gdboling (generated)", id: "1340670757336-8") {
    addPrimaryKey(columnNames: "basket_id, gift_card_id", constraintName: "basket_gift_cPK", tableName: "basket_gift_card")
}

changeSet(author: "gdboling (generated)", id: "1340670757336-16") {
    dropPrimaryKey(tableName: "basket_gift_card")
}

changeSet(author: "gdboling (generated)", id: "1340670757336-188") {
    dropColumn(columnName: "id", tableName: "basket_gift_card")
}

changeSet(author: "gdboling (generated)", id: "1340670757336-189") {
  dropColumn(columnName: "version", tableName: "basket_gift_card")
}
```

What's interesting (and wrong) about this is the order.  The dropPrimaryKey should go first, then everything else.  As is, when running dbm-update, it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have come across one of [the problems with database diffs](http://blog.liquibase.org/2007/06/the-problem-with-database-diffs.html), albeit slightly different than the example given in that post.  The migration plugin documentation was definitely not joking when it said:

> When running migration scripts on non-development databases, it's important that you backup the database before running the migration in case anything goes wrong. You could also make a copy of the database and run the script against that, and if there's a problem the real database will be unaffected.

There have been several times that I needed to make manual adjustments to changelogs that were generated with `dbm-gorm-diff`.  I think it just comes with the territory, unfortunately.  That's not to take anything away from the plugin though; it's not perfect but I feel a lot more confident about my database structure since I started using it.

Comment: Thanks for the link. So are you saying that the answer to my question is that diff is imperfect and it is not a bug?  I just want to be sure that this is truly a diff limitation vs something else.

Comment: Well... I think you could argue that generating a broken changelog IS a bug, but from the plugin side it's a liquibase issue and the liquibase 'fix' would probably be not to use diff to generate the changelog.